# Problem disabling modules via drush

Tags: 6, updating

Upon running 
`drush pm-list --type=module --status=enabled | sed '/\((.*)\)/!d;/[Cc]ore.*-.*[Rr]equired/d;s/.*(\(.*\)).*/\1/' | sort > noncoremod.txt`

I got this error:

```
The following extensions will be disabled:
.........
Do you really want to continue? (y/n): y
array_merge(): Argument #2 is not an array content.install:42        [warning]
array_merge(): Argument #2 is not an array content.install:42        [warning]
array_merge(): Argument #2 is not an array content.install:42        [warning]
array_merge(): Argument #2 is not an array content.install:42        [warning]
.........                                                            [warning]
Table &#039;profile_fields&#039; already exists                      [warning]
query: CREATE TABLE profile_fields (
`fid` INT NOT NULL auto_increment, 
`title` VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL, 
`name` VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL DEFAULT &#039;&#039;, 
`explanation` TEXT DEFAULT NULL, 
`category` VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL, 
`page` VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL, 
`type` VARCHAR(128) DEFAULT NULL, 
`weight` TINYINT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, 
`required` TINYINT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, 
`register` TINYINT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, 
`visibility` TINYINT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, 
`autocomplete` TINYINT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, 
`options` TEXT DEFAULT NULL, 
PRIMARY KEY (fid), 
UNIQUE KEY name (name), 
INDEX category (category)
) /*!40100 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 */ database.mysqli.inc:169
Table &#039;profile_values&#039; already exists                      [warning]
query: CREATE TABLE profile_values (
`fid` INT unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, 
`uid` INT unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, 
`value` TEXT DEFAULT NULL, 
PRIMARY KEY (uid, fid), 
INDEX fid (fid)
) /*!40100 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 */ database.mysqli.inc:169

array_merge(): Argument #2 is not an array content.install:42        [warning]
array_merge(): Argument #2 is not an array content.install:42        [warning]
array_merge(): Argument #2 is not an array content.install:42        [warning]
array_merge(): Argument #2 is not an array content.install:42        [warning]
.........                                                            [warning]
There was a problem disabling                                        [error]
comment,contact,help,locale,menu,path, .....
```

After that I go to `admin/build/modules` to check the modules state but I was being surprised by seeing that all the modules are enabled.

Any thoughts?

**Related issue:** http://drupal.org/node/523384

Comment: What does `drush --version` output?

Comment: @Citricguy `drush version 5.2`

Comment: I'm experiencing this too. No answer on top of my head until now.

Comment: @ninjascorner are you on 5.2 as well?  Drush is currently in version 5.7. Could you confirm that this is still broken in 5.7? http://drupal.org/project/drush

Comment: Yes I'm using 5.2. Ok I will try 5.7. But is this caused really by Drush?

Comment: Not sure, but this will help rule it out.  Are you on D6 as well?

Comment: Yes I'm in D6 too. Actually same with user8012.